# Counting exceptions leads to an UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, scope, jupyter-notebook

When I try to count exceptions in Jupyter Notebook like this:

```
read_err_cnt = 0
def clean_words(text):
  tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('[\'а-яА-Яёй]+', discard_empty=True)
  try:
      for word in tokenizer.tokenize(text):
          yield word
  except:
      read_err_cnt += 1
```

And then call:

```
clean_words(some_bad_text)
```

I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'read_err_cnt' referenced before assignment'
```

How can that be when in fact variable 'read_err_cnt' is not local?

Comment: I guess you need to specify read_err_cnt inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you assign a value to a variable inside a function you'll create a local variable. That would shadow any variables with the same name in outer scopes.

In your case the:

```
read_err_cnt += 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
read_err_cnt = read_err_cnt + 1
```

The `read_err_cnt =` part tells Python that you want to create a (local) variable called `read_err_cnt`. However in the same line you want to access the `read_err_cnt` variable from the outer scope. That's simply impossible because the local variable shadows the "outer" variable.

There are several ways to solve this, for example use `global read_err_cnt` in the function that tells Python you want to access **and modify** the global `read_err_cnt` variable. But you could also use a mutable type in the global scope and use methods of that object that modify the state:

```
err_cnt = {'read': 0}
def clean_words(text):
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('[\'а-яА-Яёй]+', discard_empty=True)
    try:
        for word in tokenizer.tokenize(text):
            yield word
    except:
        err_cnt['read'] += 1  # this assigns to the global "err_cnt" dictionary.
```

Answer (score 0):

True you just add `global read_err_cnt` inside function. 
Modified given code as below, just to demonstrate.
Then it would work with out error.

**example:**

```
read_err_cnt = 0
def clean_words(text):
    #global read_err_cnt
    tokenizer = [1,2,3,4,5]
    try:
        for word in tokenizer:
            yield word
    except:
        read_err_cnt += 1

obj = clean_words("hesfsfsdfsdafsdf sdafdsa fdsaf dsfsd")

print obj.next()
```

gave me error as:

```
Exception UnboundLocalError: "local variable 'read_err_cnt' referenced before assignment" in <generator object clean_words at 0x7fb8988231e0> ignored
```

After adding the `global read_err_cnt` to function. it worked just fine.

`In side function it is trying to assign value, or change a value, immediately that variable will become local.` Trying to increment on a variable which is not existed before. To avoid it use global keyword.

After using global keyword, If code tries to reference global variable, inside function the assignment is just working, as variable is already exists.